# How can I change how VSCode works when using "Add missing attributes" for JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm using Visual Studio Code to create some TypeScript JSX for a React project.

There's some undesirable behavior when using the "Add missing attributes" option under "Quick Fix"

[image]

Here's what I want VSCode to create for me.

[image]

However, what actually happens is VSCode initializes these attributes to what is, in my opinion, just garbage. I have to spend a bunch of time deleting these placeholder values.

[image]

I've tried using the following preferences to only auto-complete with braces, and make no attempt to fill out the attribute. The documentation for these settings seems to suggest this would work.

```
"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "braces",
"typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "braces",
```

However, it doesn't. It only seems to control the case where one begins to type in an attribute and VSCode prompts to auto complete it.

Does anyone know how to get VSCode to only put in empty braces when using "Add missing attributes"?

Comment: Just `Ctrl`+`Space` and `Tab` until all the missing fields are added